# How to push new object nested array properties in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

> Here is course schema and I want to push **content object**, but I can't find what is a good way. help please.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  course_en: { type: String },
  course: { type: String },
  module: [
    {
      _id: { 
        type: String
      },
      module_en: String,
      module: String,
      content: [
        {
            _id: { type: String }
          content_en: String,
          content: String,
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
});

const Course = mongoose.model("Course", Schema);

export default Course;
```

> Here is my tried code but don't work, it only work to add **module object**

```
db.update(
      { _id: _id, "module._id": module_id },
      {
        $push: { content: data } 
      }
    )
    .then((result: any) => {
      console.log(`Content Posted ${result}`);
      response.send({ "status": "success" });
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`);
      response.send({ "status": "fail" });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.update(
{ _id: _id, "module._id": module_id },
{ "$push": 
    {"module.$.content": 
        {
            "_id":"123",
            "content_en": "hello",
            "content": "hey"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah, done my work. I really appreciate it! Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is the object you want to add to `content` array, you can try something like this:

```
db.update(
      { _id: _id, "module._id": module_id },
      {
        $push: { "module.$.content" : data } 
      }
)
```